# SSH Tunnel for RDP

Tags: ssh, rdp, putty

I have my PC in LAN at work (PC-WORK 192.168.1.x)
and a SSH server with one interface looking at LAN (PC-SSH 192.168.1.xx) and WAN (88.88.88.88)

What I need is to get Remote Desktop to PC-WORK from home(PC-HOME).

How can I make it using Putty?
What I made is I created a tunnel from my PC-WORK(192.168.1.x) to SSH server, so that it listens:

```
#lsof -i -nP | grep 3390
sshd  18598   root   11u  IPv4 592868957   TCP 127.0.0.1:3390 (LISTEN)
```

and redirects localhost:3333 to my PC:3389.

What's the next step?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect by Putty and forward local port 3333 to PC-WORK:3390: Connection->SSH->Tunnels; Source port - 3333; Destination - PC-WORK:3389. Press 'Add'

Comment: but don't i need to make a tunnel to PC-SSH from home first? i think have already done what you wrote

Comment: So, just connect to Start-Run-"mstsc /v:localhost:3333"

Comment: Ok i finally got it:
PCWORK:
R6333
localhost:3389
Remote ipv4

PCHOME:
L3336
212.154.169.42:6333
Local ipv4
mstsc /v:127.0.0.1:3336